# Как проверить наличие значения строки в таблице swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Есть таблица в `UIViewController`. В методе `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, при нажатии на любую троку в таблице мне нужно прверить, а существует ли значение в следующей строке от нажатой

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let record = self.records[indexPath.row]
        let record2 = self.records[indexPath.row + 1]
```

То есть нужно узнать существует ли значения `record2`, если да, то дальше работать с ним, если нет, то ничего не делать

Спасибо

Comment: if indexPath.row+1 < records.count { ... }

Comment: @OlegSoloviev Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard indexPath.row < self.records.count - 1 else { return }
        let record = self.records[indexPath.row]
        // Дальнейший код
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это я уже пробовал. Появляется ошибка `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Records'`

Comment: @StanislavPutilov немного изменил код, попробуйте в таком варианте